# Looping an apps script for every row of google sheet

Tags: javascript, loops, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've created a HTML file that sends responses to a timesheet to a spreadsheet in a string. What I'm now trying to do is take the data from each row, and pasting it into a readable format, which is then sent off as a PDF to the email address included in the string of data. Eventually I will make this script run from a button on a separate sheet (as to why I've made reference to the sheetID).

I've got the script working for one string, but I still need to make the code iterative for each row, without just copying and pasting the code over and over and changing the values.

```
function sendPDF() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1Zsinv7scuXLn1Eq-8frtMHOTnunFYtFk2x3iAynHkaU");
  var sh = spreadsheet.getSheets()[1]
  var sh1 = spreadsheet.getSheets()[0]
  var shName = sh.getName()
  var spreadsheeta = spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('data dump'), true)
  var spreadsheetb = spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('PDF file'), true)
  var paste = SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES

// below is the section that needs reiterating for each row in 'spreadsheeta'

spreadsheeta.getRange("A3").copyTo(spreadsheetb.getRange("D4"), paste, false);
spreadsheeta.getRange("D3").copyTo(spreadsheetb.getRange("H5"), paste,false);
spreadsheeta.getRange("H3:I3").copyTo(spreadsheetb.getRange("C9"), paste,false);
spreadsheeta.getRange("J3:K3").copyTo(spreadsheetb.getRange("F9"), paste,false);
spreadsheeta.getRange("R3:S3").copyTo(spreadsheetb.getRange("C10"), paste,false);
spreadsheeta.getRange("T3:U3").copyTo(spreadsheetb.getRange("F10"), paste,false);
spreadsheeta.getRange("AB3:AC3").copyTo(spreadsheetb.getRange("C11"), paste,false);
spreadsheeta.getRange("AD3:AE3").copyTo(spreadsheetb.getRange("F11"), paste,false);
spreadsheeta.getRange("AL3:AM3").copyTo(spreadsheetb.getRange("C12"), paste,false);
spreadsheeta.getRange("AN3:AO3").copyTo(spreadsheetb.getRange("F12"), paste,false);
spreadsheeta.getRange("AV3:AW3").copyTo(spreadsheetb.getRange("C13"), paste,false);
spreadsheeta.getRange("AX3:AY3").copyTo(spreadsheetb.getRange("F13"), paste,false);
spreadsheeta.getRange("BF3:BG3").copyTo(spreadsheetb.getRange("C14"), paste,false);
spreadsheeta.getRange("BH3:BI3").copyTo(spreadsheetb.getRange("F14"), paste,false);
spreadsheeta.getRange("BP3:BQ3").copyTo(spreadsheetb.getRange("C15"), paste,false);
spreadsheeta.getRange("BR3:BS3").copyTo(spreadsheetb.getRange("F15"), paste,false);
spreadsheeta.getRange("BZ3:CA3").copyTo(spreadsheetb.getRange("C16"), paste,false);
spreadsheeta.getRange("CB3:CC3").copyTo(spreadsheetb.getRange("F16"), paste,false);
spreadsheeta.getRange("CJ3:CK3").copyTo(spreadsheetb.getRange("C17"), paste,false);
spreadsheeta.getRange("CL3:CM3").copyTo(spreadsheetb.getRange("F17"), paste,false);
spreadsheeta.getRange("CT3:CU3").copyTo(spreadsheetb.getRange("C18"), paste,false);
spreadsheeta.getRange("CV3:CW3").copyTo(spreadsheetb.getRange("F18"), paste,false);
spreadsheeta.getRange("DD3:DE3").copyTo(spreadsheetb.getRange("C19"), paste,false);
spreadsheeta.getRange("DF3:DG3").copyTo(spreadsheetb.getRange("F19"), paste,false);
spreadsheeta.getRange("DN3:DO3").copyTo(spreadsheetb.getRange("C20"), paste,false);
spreadsheeta.getRange("DP3:DQ3").copyTo(spreadsheetb.getRange("F20"), paste,false);
spreadsheeta.getRange("DN3:DO3").copyTo(spreadsheetb.getRange("C20"), paste,false);
spreadsheeta.getRange("DP3:DQ3").copyTo(spreadsheetb.getRange("F20"), paste,false);
spreadsheeta.getRange("DX3:DY3").copyTo(spreadsheetb.getRange("C21"), paste,false);
spreadsheeta.getRange("DZ3:EA3").copyTo(spreadsheetb.getRange("F21"), paste,false);
spreadsheeta.getRange("EH3:EI3").copyTo(spreadsheetb.getRange("C22"), paste,false);
spreadsheeta.getRange("EJ3:EK3").copyTo(spreadsheetb.getRange("F22"), paste,false);
spreadsheeta.getRange("ER3:ES3").copyTo(spreadsheetb.getRange("C23"), paste,false);
spreadsheeta.getRange("ET3:EU3").copyTo(spreadsheetb.getRange("F23"), paste,false);
spreadsheeta.getRange("FB3:FC3").copyTo(spreadsheetb.getRange("C24"), paste,false);
spreadsheeta.getRange("FD3:FE3").copyTo(spreadsheetb.getRange("F24"), paste,false);
spreadsheeta.getRange("E3").copyTo(spreadsheetb.getRange("H28"), paste,false);

  sendSpreadsheetToPdf(1, shName, sh1.getRange('B3').getValue(),"test email with the adress in cell A1 ", "This is it !");
};

//I've then got another function to print and sent the pdf to the recipient in cell b3
```

Comment: Welcome to [so]. It looks that you used code generated by the macro recorder as the base of your script as it includes several `Range.activate()` lines. While using the macro recorder could be convenient to automate simple tasks, it generates very slow scripts which might be generated maximum execution time limit errors when using the generated code in a loop. To avoid this, spend some time learning the basics of JavaScript, i.e. to eliminate unnecessary lines like `spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('data dump'), true);
  spreadsheet.getRange('A3').activate();`

Comment: Thank you @Rubén I've gone through the script and shortened it, so now I can include the whole script. Also, the script is now running about 60x faster, so thanks again! I'm just struggling with figuring out how to make the script reiterate for each row of 'spreadsheeta'

Comment: Thanks for your reply reece. It's not clear how the destination should be determined for each range to be copied, they belong to the same row but destinations don't.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
var spreadsheeta = spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('data dump'), true)
var spreadsheetb = spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('PDF file'), true)
```

by

```
var spreadsheeta = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('data dump');
var spreadsheetb = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('PDF file');
```

This will make your script faster.

Then instead of using the A1 notation range references as parameter of `Sheet.getRange()` use row, column, number of rows and number of columns as parameters, i.e.

- instead of `spreadsheeta.getRange("A3")` use `spreadsheeta.getRange(i,1)`
- instead `spreadsheeta.getRange("H3:I3")` use `spreadsheeta.getRange(i,8,1,2)`

where `i` is a variable that will be modified on each loop iteration, i.e.,

```
for(let i = 3; i <= spreadsheeta.getLastRow(); i++){
  // put here the stuff to be done on each iteration
}
```

Note: Google Apps Script has a maximum execution time quota of 6 minutes for free accounts, and 30 minutes for Workspace accounts. Considering this, you might have to process the rows in batches. One alternative option is to use `batchUpdate` from the Advanced Sheets Service.

Related

- [how to reduce runtime of google app script that using setValues() and copyto() in for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62826505/1595451)